# Convert .d.ts to HTML documentation

Tags: typescript, documentation

I have a typescript declaration file (.d.ts) which contains documentation about every function of an API. I want to display the documentation in a website (.html).

Is there a way to do that? (Convert a .d.ts to nice looking .html)

(Note: I don't have the .ts files, only the .d.ts file)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this nuget project :

https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc

TypeDoc runs on Node.js and is available as an NPM package. You can install TypeDoc in your project's directory as usual:

```
$ npm install typedoc --save-dev
```

Like the TypeScript compiler, TypeDoc comes with a binary that can be called from anywhere if you install TypeDoc as a global module. The name of the executable is typedoc.

```
$ npm install typedoc --global
$ typedoc
```

### Usage

### Shell

TypeDoc accepts most of the command line arguments that the TypeScript compiler accepts. One major difference is the fact that one may pass an entire directory instead of individual files to the documentation generator. So in order to create a documentation for an entire project you simply type:

```
$ typedoc --out path/to/documentation/ path/to/typescript/project/
```

Comment: I don't find a way to use typedoc for creating the documentation from d.ts files, without the matching .ts files, using:

```
 npx typedoc lib/entity-bundle.d.ts
```

results in the error...
```
Warning: Unable to locate entry point: /Users/gabry/projects/arena-backend/lib/entity-bundle.d.ts
Error: Unable to find any entry points. Make sure TypeDoc can find your tsconfig
```

Comment: Same here. This answer needs to be downvoted as it does not answer the original question.